# Permutation Cycles

Tags: algorithm

I am working on an interesting permutation cycle problem. We know any permutation of numbers is made up of disjoint cycles of numbers. For example let's say our original permutation is 12345. After one cycle the permutation becomes 14235. So 1 ==> 1, 2==>3, 3==>4, 4==2, and 5==>5. So our disjoint cycles, are
1, 234, and 5. Let's say we cycled like this 10^10 times. What is the end result? For example after one more cycle we get to 13425. I want to do this as efficiently as possible. Obviously we want to do modular arithmetic because there is a pattern, but how to write up this code in Java? Thanks

Comment: You can just modulus your large number with the number of repeating cycles (in this case 3).  Then you only need to run the cycle 0 - 3 times and you know the value for any input number.

Comment: Please see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: Thanks, this is not a homework question, just a practice competition coding problem outside of school

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to use your modular arithmetic insight on each disjoint cycle *independently*.

For your example, you can get the result of 10^10 cycles

1. of the first disjoint cycle (1) trivially
2. of the second disjoint cycle (234) by cycling it (10^10)%3 = 1 times
3. of the third disjoint cycle (5) trivially

That just leaves *finding* the disjoint cycles, but that wasn't part of your question.

Comment: But if each of my disjoint cycles is very long ( say of length 10^5) then cycling the entire permutation at most 10^5 times still feels kind of inefficient right? For example my idea was rather look where each individual element goes. For example 10^10 mod 3 is 1, so 2 moves one spot to the right, same with 3 and 4. But then my issue is efficiently finding which disjoint cycle each element belongs to right?

Comment: "That just leaves finding the disjoint cycles, but that wasn't part of your question" -- maybe you need a new question?

Comment: Efficiency is measured relative to the size of the problem instance.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can apply the same strategy as when implementing the calculation of a power `a^n` efficiently.

`N` can be decomposed as `N = n[0] + n[1] 2 + n[2] 2^2 + ... + n[k] 2^k`, with `n[i] = 0 or 1`

Applying the permutation `P` N times correspond to implement a permutation

```
P[N] = P[1]^n[0] x P[2]^n[1] x P[4]^n[2] x ... x P[2^k]^n[k] with P[1] = P
```

Where `x` corresponds to the composition of permutations.

Here, we use the conventions `P[.]^0 = I` (identity) and `P[.]^1 = P[.]`

The permutations `P[2^i]` can be calculated iteratively: `P[2^i] = P[2^(i-1)] x P[2^(i-1)]` as the `n[i]`.

Complexity: O(p logN) where `p` is the size of the permutation